# Login success on FTP over explicit SSL/TLS but unable to browse the files

Tags: java, ssl, ftp

I have been asked to make the secure FTP Server connection. FTP over explicit TLS/SSL. In order to achieve this, I have added a below line in the existing implementation. This is my FTPClient lib - it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j - version 1.6.1

ftpClient.setSecurity(FTPClient.SECURITY_FTPES);

// Existing code

`ftpClient.setConnector(new HTTPTunnelConnector(proxyHost, proxyPort));
ftpClient.connect(getFtpHost(), getFtpPort());
ftpClient.login(getUsername(), getPassword());
ftpClient.setAutoNoopTimeout(30000);`

When I deployed the code on JBOSS 5.1, I am getting successful connection, but I am unable to list the files in the root directory. we only have permission to access the root directory.

On the other hand, I have written a standalone client (java main program) - through which I can print the files present at FTP location, by this way I have ensured the secure connection and the files availability at FTP location. Here, I have used the

My problem is, when I make a secure connection through the deployed application I am getting the unable to locate any files at remote location. ie: FTPFiles.length is 0

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Adding few more logs and info,
Normal Flow without FTPES security parameter added (current Implementation)

**printing ftpClient.serverStatus()**

`msg: Status of 'FTP Service'
msg:  Connected from ec2-xyz
msg:  Logged in as <user>
msg:  TYPE: BINARY, STRUcture: File, Mode: Stream
msg:  Total bytes transferred for session: 10511
msg:  No data connection
msg: End of status`

**printing ftpClient.serverStatus() With FTPES added**

`msg: Status of 'FTP Service'
msg:  Connected from ec2-xyz
msg:  Logged in as <user>
msg:  TYPE: ASCII, STRUcture: File, Mode: Stream
msg:  No data connection
msg: End of status`

Few questions which I need to know answers (may be that give a lead to fix):

1. Here, TYPE: BINARY is changed to ASCII and can someone tell how to modify back to BINARY? Note tehre is no explicit setting made, got changed post FTPES set
2. Is this issue related to proxy / port. if so - I wont be able to provide those information.
3. As of now, I am testing with same proxy used which is used in the application.
4. Is there any certificates to be imported to get files viewed / downloaded.
5. Found this on net which is exactly same as my issue, http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/TLS.html ( search for -"I can login using FTPS, but I cannot see any directories. Why not?") but I need to explain my third party to make the required change... what should I tell?

**stand alone client code**

```
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.List;

public class FTPWithSSL {
    private static FTPClient ftpClient;
    private static FTPConfig ftpConfig;
    private DailyFTPConfig config;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        ftpConfig = new FTPConfig("username", "password", "FTPServer.net", 21, setupConnector());

        FTPDownloader ftpDownloader = new FTPDownloader(ftpConfig, new FTPDownloadController() {
            @Override
            public List<FTPFile> download(FTPClient ftpClient) throws Exception {
                downloadFile(ftpClient);
                System.out.println("download success");
                return null;
            }
        });
        try {
            openConnection();
            List<FTPFile> ftpFileList = ftpDownloader.download();
            closeConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void openConnection() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("OpenConnection method");
        if (ftpClient == null) {
            ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            // Even if the below line is commented, the code works fine
            ftpClient.setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory());

            System.out.println("setting FTPES here");
            ftpClient.setSecurity(FTPClient.SECURITY_FTPES);
            ftpClient.setConnector(ftpConfig.getConnector());
            ftpClient.connect(ftpConfig.getFtpHost(), ftpConfig.getFtpPort());
            ftpClient.login(ftpConfig.getUsername(), ftpConfig.getPassword());
            ftpClient.setAutoNoopTimeout(30000);
            System.out.println("ftpClient.isConnected() " + ftpClient.isConnected());
        }
    }

    private static SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory() throws Exception {
        TrustManager[] trustManager = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        } };
        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustManager, new SecureRandom());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        return sslSocketFactory;

    }
    private static void closeConnection() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("ftpClient.serverStatus() -- ");
        for (String serverStatus : ftpClient.serverStatus()) {
            System.out.println(" msg: " + serverStatus);
        }
        if (ftpClient != null && ftpClient.isConnected()) {
            ftpClient.disconnect(false);
        }
    }

    private static void downloadFile(FTPClient ftpClient) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("ftpsClient.currentDirectory() " + ftpClient.currentDirectory());
        FTPFile[] ftpFile = ftpClient.list();
        System.out.println("Name " + ftpFile[0].getName());
        System.out.println("Link " + ftpFile[0].getLink());
        System.out.println("Modified Date " + ftpFile[0].getModifiedDate());


        String[] listnames = ftpClient.listNames();
        System.out.println("ftpsClient.listNames() " +listnames);

        System.out.println("ftpsClient.currentDirectory() " + ftpClient.list());
        File file = new File( "C:\\opt\\copycat\\a1234.zip");
        System.out.println("Downloading File: [" + file.getName() + "] has started.");
        ftpClient.download("a1234.zip", file);
        System.out.println("Downloading File: has Completed");
    }

    private static FTPConnector setupConnector() {
        FTPConnector connector = new DirectConnector();
        String proxyHost = "amazonaws.com";
        if (proxyHost != null) {
            System.out.println("proxy host NOT NULL");
            int proxyPort = Integer.parseInt("123");
            connector = new HTTPTunnelConnector(proxyHost, proxyPort);
        }
        return connector;
    }
}
```

Comment: So there must be a difference between the code in your application and the code in your test (console?) application. And you didn't show us any of those codes.

Comment: It is just an inserted main java class which invokes the application flow in the mid to download the files, also added few sysouts in it. .. one difference is - proxy value set, in application it has a proxy used in the client network, whereas the main class contain AWS/ squid proxy

Comment: So you know the difference and you didn't bothered to mention it in the question?!?

Comment: Apologise, are you expecting that detail?

Comment: That's not a details, that's a important piece of information. Edit that into your question. No one can answer your question, without knowing that.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - just to confirm there is no difference in proxy. Now I am adding few more line of codes to make it clear

Comment: So can you browse the files using FTP TLS/SSL client? Show us its log file.

Comment: Yes.
proxy host NOT NULL
OpenConnection method
setting FTPES here
ftpClient.isConnected() true
ftpsClient.currentDirectory() /
Downloading File: [a1234.zip] has started.
ftpClient.serverStatus()
 msg: Status of 'FTP Service'
 msg:  Connected from amazonaws.com
 msg:  Logged in as user1
 msg:  TYPE: ASCII, STRUcture: File, Mode: Stream
 msg:  No data connection
 msg: End of status

Comment: Sorry, I give up, I do not understand your question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am able to make the secure connection and able to download the latest files from FTP server using FTPES (FTP over explicit TLS/SSL).
I have made only 2 line code changes (below), in the actual implementation. earlier it was having the list() method to get the files from FTP server, and its return type is FTPFile[]

This is the code changes which I made, and other line of codes are modified / removed.

```
    ftpClient.setSecurity(FTPClient.SECURITY_FTPES);
// get the FTP connection
    String[] fileNames = ftpClient.listNames();

// Exisitng implementation
FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftpClient.list("*.zip");
// after that there is an implementation for getting the latest files using the Comparator<FTPFile>
```

There was an issue with the LIST  command's output, ie: LIST *.zip is not giving the correct output (I guess)